# Expert wanted AngularFire2 firestore nested collection get data?

Tags: firebase, nested, angular6, angularfire2, rxjs6

Hey I couldn't find how can i do nested query in firestore ?

```
this.match1 = this.MatchCollection1.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Matches;
        const uid = data.pairer;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        const photourl = afs.collection(`users/${uid}/photos`,
            ref => ref.where('index', '==', 0).where('deleted', '==', false)).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(action => {
            return action.map(p => {
                const pdata = p.payload.doc.data() as Photos;
                return pdata.url;
            });
        }));
        return {id, uid, url: photourl, ...data};
    });
}));
```

My problem photourl return observable how can i do return object like others

Comment: Who know this ?

Comment: Can you provide your data structure and explain what kind results you expect?

Comment: I want photourl to string

Answer (score 0):

A bit tricky to follow but I think all you need to do is move your return {id, uid, url: photourl, ...data};  From what I can see you are just missing a subscription to unpack your observable and extract the value. EG

```
 return action.map(p => {
              const pdata = p.payload.doc.data() as Photos;
              return pdata.url;
            });
          })).subscribe(photo => {
"if you want to set photourl do it here photourl = photo.url;"
            return photo; //do what you need to before you return the actual 
photo object.

          });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **toPromise** method with **async await**.

Data structure

```
users
  | userId1
      | photos
          | photoId1
                | url : 'someURL'
          | photoId2
                | url : 'someURL2'
```

Service or component file

```
items;
getPhotos(uid){
  return this.db.collection(`users/${uid}/photos`).valueChanges()
  .pipe(first()).toPromise() // get first stream and return it as promise
}

async fooFunc() {

  let user_id = 'userId1' //TODO: get user uid from somewhere

  this.items = await this.getPhotos(user_id) // await getPhotos promise finish
  console.log(this.items) // return [Object, Object]
}
```

component html template

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{ item | json }}
</li>
```

output

```
{ "url": "someURL" }
{ "url": "someURL2" }
```